# how to copy array?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have four arrays as follows:

```
toArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"to 1",@"to 2",@"to 3",@"to 4",@"to 5",@"to 6",@"to 7",nil]; 
fromArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"from 1",@"from 2",@"from 3",@"from 4",@"from 5",@"from 6",@"from 7",nil]; 
messageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"message 1",@"message 2",@"message 3",@"message 4",@"message 5",@"message 6",@"message 7",nil]; 
dayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"day 1",@"day 2",@"day 3",@"day 4",@"day 5",@"day 6",@"day 7",nil];
```

I want to copy or create a single array which should contain all these 4 arrays.
How can i achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "contain" `[[1a,1b],[2a,2b]]` or `[1a,1b,2a,2b]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous; how do you want the result?

```
NSMutableArray *completeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[completeArray addObjectsFromArray:toArray];
[completeArray addObjectsFromArray:fromArray];
[completeArray addObjectsFromArray:messageArray];
[completeArray addObjectsFromArray:dayArray];
```

Or

```
NSMutableArray *completeArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:toArray, fromArray, messageArray, dayArray, nil];
```

Or if all arrays have the same number of elements:

```
NSMutableArray *completeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [toArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", [toArray objectAtIndex:i], [fromArray objectAtIndex:i], [messageArray objectAtIndex:i], [dayArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [completeArray addObject:fullString];
}
```

Or, as an array of dictionaries (also assuming all arrays are same length):

```
NSMutableArray *completeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [toArray count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [toArray objectAtIndex:i], @"to",
        [fromArray objectAtIndex:i], @"from",
        [messageArray objectAtIndex:i], @"message",
        [dayArray objectAtIndex:i], @"day",
        nil];
    [completeArray addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: thank dreamlax....for showing me so many ways of achieving that...
i really appreciate u.

regards
shishir

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSArray *singleArray = [NSArray arrayWithElements:toArray, fromArray, messsageArray, dayArray, nil]; 
// mind the nil element at the end
```

Comment: There's no method called `+arrayWithElements:`. Do you mean `+arrayWithObjects:`?

Comment: actually i need to show info like in this manner

to1
from1 
message1
day1

to2
from2 
message2
day2

to3
from3 
message3
day3

something like dat,in a table view.

wat should i do to get this patter in table view.??

thank Eimantas,for a quick reply 

regards

Comment: yes, i meant `+arrayWithObjects:`. I presume you're creating some sort of message list. You'll need an array with dictionaries where each dictionary would hold one message (i.e. represent one row for a table).

Comment: @eimantas,, can u plz guide me,how should i do this.

regards
shishir

Comment: NOw now wen i got all three array in a single array,

how can i set array into table view??

showing something like dis

to1
from1
message1
day1
--------------
to2
from2
message2
day2
--------------
to3
from3
message3
day4
--------------


like in this pattern????

Comment: read about NSTableViewDataSource protocol in apple documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

[result addObjectsFromArray:toArray];
[result addObjectsFromArray:fromArray];
[result addObjectsFromArray:messageArray];
[result addObjectsFromArray:dayArray];
```

Comment: What is the reason for "arrayWithCapacity: 0"?  Why not just "array"

Comment: i hv an array ("array A") in class "A".

and in class "B",i m having another array ("array B"),which fills tableview,of class "B" only.

i need to fill tableview,with the values of class A's array (i.e array A).

how can i do it??

how to copy array from another class ?

i hope i m clear with my question

regards shishir